# Nested for loop in python not workin with range(0, i+1) but working with range(0, i)

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

This code is working fine :

```
list2 = [3, 3, 3]
print(list2)
for i in list2 :
    for j in range(0, i)  :
        list2.append(j)
print(list2)
```

This code is not running or may be taking a lot of time :

```
list2 = [3, 3, 3]
print(list2)
for i in list2 :
    for j in range(0, i + 1)  :
        list2.append(j)
print(list2)
```

Comment: Debug your code. Add a print statement after `list2.append(j)`. What happens?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? what does happen? what happens when it does "work"? You should never append or remove from the list you're currently iterating over

Comment: Also - your 4 inputs are not needed, use fixed values: `list2 = [2,3,4]` - `n` is never used at all, same for `result`.  Read and follow [mre]!

Comment: I edited the question to add concrete inputs... please dont' give an example that requires user input unless user-input is a relevant part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is : `for i in list2` iterate also on the numbers added by `list2.append(j)`

---

1. In the first code, the inner loop only add numbers that are smaller than the ones already in `list2`, as the range end bound is exclusive, if `list2 = [3,3,3]` then you'll add 0,1,2, then 0,1, then 0 then range yields nothing
2. But in the second case, the range now generates until the given bound too, so it's an infitite loop, as

   ```
   i=0
   range(0, 0+1) => [0] added in `list2`
   iterate on the added `0`

   i=0
   range(0, 0+1) => [0] added in `list2`
   iterate on the added `0`
   ...
   ```

---

If you don't want to iterate on the new numbers, make a copy

```
list2 = [3, 3, 3]
for i in list(list2):
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        list2.append(j)

# [3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note

Each value will generates `2**x` values, it the initial list contains multiple items, sum their power of 2

```
from random import choice
init = [choice(range(10)), choice(range(10)), choice(range(10))]
list2 = list(init)
for i in list2:
    for j in range(i):
        list2.append(j)
assert len(list2) == sum(2 ** x for x in init)
```

Comment: You took the words out of my keyboard. Also the `result = []` declaration after the loops seems weird. Could the OP wanted to append on `result` instead `list2`?

Comment: This is interesting. The problem with the `+` version is that it will always add at least one, hence it will keep going. But when it isn't inclusive, I'm not sure how to analyze this. Maybe I'm missing something. It stops because eventually, there are enough zeros added that the iteration can "catch up"  and terminate. But will this always happen? Can't wrap my head around it. Time to go to sleep...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga first version adds many numbers but always smaller so it'll end for sure, but can be afer a long time

Comment: Ahhh ok. No I get it now.  It will always end eventually because it will always add a series of numbers that is one less than. Had to stick an `input()` and `print(list2)` at the end of the loop.

Comment: yes!  eventually you reach zero since the numbers you add are always decreasing. There a cool number theory problem in here for how many iterations it will take. But I'm definitely going to sleep now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga each value will yield for `2**x`, so it you have multiple value in initial list, sum that, I've edit my post to add that